# Passing PHP session to different folder

Tags: php

how do you pass a PHP session value to different folders?

I have this index page in the localhost.

**localhost/index.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['Username'] = 'Hello';
  header('Location: ../AnotherFolder/index.php');
?>
```

In here, I want to echo the **$_SESSION['Username']** on other sub-folder

**AnotherFolder/index.php**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  echo $_SESSION['Username'];
?>
```

Comment: And does this not work? What error do you get?

Comment: this should work. if you start session on every page then you can access session values in any page whether in same folder or in other

Comment: Nothing wrong with this code. Make sure the other file location is correct `../AnotherFolder/index.php`

Comment: @Sébastien when I echo the session value it does not display any value. Is there a problem

Answer (score 0):

I'd also check whether or not your session storage is working properly.  Perhaps the session is never being started.

Find this in your php ini

`;session.save_path = "/tmp"`

uncomment it, and make sure you have appropriate permissions set for the www-user in the tmp folder.

Refresh your page, and then check the folder to see if a session file is being created.

If not, you've got bigger problems than you think.